# Which class of problems is this?

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving

I’m working on a problem which I will try my best to describe:

- You have a stack of 5 blocks: labelled A, B, C, D and E.
- You also have a set of rules giving points if certain conditions are met, for example: B is above D (1 point), D is above A (0.75 points), A is above D (0.25 points) etc.
- The goal is to stack the blocks in such a way as to maximise the number of points from the goals. Some goals are contradictory so not all goals can necessarily be met.

I would like to understand which kind of general class of problems it is, in order to find a general way to solve it. Is it a graph traversal, [bin packing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) or some other class of problems?

Comment: It looks like a specific instance of an optimization problem. You're trying to maximize an objective function such that constraints are met. You may want to read more on [mathematical optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization), [operations research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_research) or [combinatorial optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to classify this problem. For example:

- [**combinatorics**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) : it’s about choosing and combining elements in a way to comply with rules/constraints ([combinatorial analysis](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Combinatorial_analysis)) and find an optimal solution ([combinatorial optimization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization)).
- **[graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)**: the blocks are nodes, the possibility to stack them is a directed edge between two nodes, and a stack is a [path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) in that graph. It is then an [optimal path finding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) problem.